# issue in dynamic validation textfield

Tags: javascript

I want to validate my dynamic text field, I am using javascript.

In this line i am getting the error

```
<aui:form name="frmaddTravelDetails" id="frmaddTravelDetails" action="<%=processActionURL.toString()%>"  method="post" onSubmit="return validateAllInputBoxes(event)">
```

error message:

> Cannot return from outside a function or method.

view.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >


  function addRow(tableID) {

        //var uniqueId=1;

        var rowid = window.document.getElementById(1).id;
        alert("First row id-->"+rowid);
          var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        alert("value of rowCount"+rowCount);

        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

         var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
         var element1 = document.createElement("input");
         element1.type = "checkbox";
         element1.name="selectDel[]"+rowCount;

           //cell1.appendChild(element1);

          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1) ;
          var element2 = document.createElement("input");
          element2.type = "text";
          //element2.name = "t02Traveldate[]" +rowCount;
          element2.name = "t02Traveldate" +rowCount;

           //cell2.appendChild(element2);

          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var element3 = document.createElement("input");
          element3.type = "text";
          element3.name = "t02Travelfrom"+rowCount;
          element3.value='';
          //cell3.appendChild(element3);

          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var element4 = document.createElement("input");
          element4.type = "text";
          element4.name = "t02Travelto"+rowCount;
          //cell4.appendChild(element4);

          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var element5 = document.createElement("input");
          element5.type = "text";
          element5.name = "t02Landmark"+rowCount;
          //cell5.appendChild(element5);

          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
          var element6 = document.createElement("input");
          element6.type = "text";
          element6.name = "t02Totalkm"+rowCount;
          //cell6.appendChild(element6); 

          var uniqueId;
        /* Start */
        for (var i=rowCount;rowCount>7;i++){

              uniqueId = i;
            //uniqueId=rowCount;
             alert("Value of unique id-->"+uniqueId);

             cell1.appendChild(element1);
             cell2.appendChild(element2);
             cell3.appendChild(element3);
             cell4.appendChild(element4);
             cell5.appendChild(element5);
             cell6.appendChild(element6);

             document.getElementById("hdn").value=uniqueId;
             document.frmaddTravelDetails.submit();


        }
          /* End */

      }   function send(tableID)  {       alert("call send function");
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount1 = table.rows.length;
        document.<portlet:namespace/>frmaddTravelDetails.<portlet:namespace/>hdn.value
= ""+rowCount1;
        document.<portlet:namespace/>frmaddTravelDetails.submit();

      }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
          try {
          var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
          var rowCount = table.rows.length;

          for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
              var row = table.rows[i];
              var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
              if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {


                  if(rowCount <= 8) {

                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                      break;
                  }
                  table.deleteRow(i);
                  rowCount--;
                  i--;
              }


          }
          }catch(e) {
              alert(e);
          }
      }    stopEvent = function(ffevent)  {
    var current_window = window;

    if(current_window.event) //window.event is IE, ffevent is FF
    {
       //IE
       current_window.event.cancelBubble = true; //this stops event propagation
       current_window.event.returnValue = false; //this prevents default (usually is what we want)
    }
    else
    {
       //Firefox
       ffevent.stopPropagation();
       ffevent.preventDefault();
    };  }

 function validateAllInputBoxes(ffevent)  {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
       if(inputs[i].type === 'text')

          if(inputs[i].length==0) 
          {
             alert("form could not be sent one input text field is empty");
             stopEvent(ffevent);
          }  }


    </script>   </head> <body>   <portlet:actionURL name="processAction" var="processActionURL"/> 
     <%
         EMP_DETAIL empDetail=(EMP_DETAIL) request.getAttribute("empDetail");   %>
    <aui:form name="frmaddTravelDetails" id="frmaddTravelDetails" action="<%=processActionURL.toString()%>"  method="post" onSubmit="return validateAllInputBoxes(event)">
    <table id="dataTable" border="1">

      <tr>
      <th colspan="7" style="text-align:center;">Employee Travel Details</th></tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
            <td colspan="6">

            <aui:input name="t02Emplid" label="" type="text"  value='<%=empDetail.getM01Emplid() %>' /></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Employee Name</td>
            <td colspan="6"><aui:input name="t02Ename" label="" type="text" value='<%=empDetail.getM01Empname() %>' /></td>
       </tr>       
       <tr>
            <td>Vehicle Type</td>
            <td colspan="6">

                <aui:select   name="t02Vechiletype" label="" id="selectedVehicle">

                <c:forEach items="${empVehicleList}" var="empVehicle" >

                    <aui:option value="${empVehicle.m04Vehicle_Type}" >${empVehicle.m04Vehicle_Type}</aui:option>

                </c:forEach>

                </aui:select>           </td>       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>Approver</td>
             <td colspan="6">
             <aui:select  name="t02Approver" label="" id="selectedApprover">


                <% List<String> listMangers = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("listManagers");

                Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(listMangers);
                System.out.println("SIZE "+set.size());
                 for (String managerList : set){
                    %>

                    <aui:option value="<%=managerList%>" ><%=managerList%></aui:option>

            <%
                }           %>



             </aui:select>  
            </td>
       </tr>                    <tr>            <td>Vehicle Number</td>
            <td colspan="6">

                <aui:input name="t02Vechileno" id="t02Vechileno" type="text" maxlength="10" label="" value="" >
                 <aui:validator name="required"  errorMessage="this-field-is-required"/> 
                 <aui:validator name="alphanum" />
                </aui:input> 
                </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select</td>

            <td>Date(dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
            <td>From</td>
            <td>To</td>
            <td>Landmark</td>
            <td colspan="6">Total KM</td>
      </tr>      
       <tr id=1>
            <td><aui:input name="selectDel" type="checkbox" label=""/></TD>

            <td>
                 <aui:input name="t02Traveldate" type="text" value="" label="">
                <aui:validator name="date" />   
                  </aui:input>

            </td>
            <td>
                <aui:input name="t02Travelfrom" type="text" label="" maxlength="15" value="">

                    <aui:validator name="required"  errorMessage="this-field-is-required"/>
                    <aui:validator name="alpha" />

                 </aui:input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <aui:input name="t02Travelto" type="text" label=""  maxlength="15" value="" >

                    <aui:validator name="required"  errorMessage="this-field-is-required"/>
                    <aui:validator name="alpha" />

                </aui:input>
            </td>     
            <td>
                <aui:input name="t02Landmark" type="text" label=""  maxlength="15" value="">

                    <aui:validator name="required"  errorMessage="this-field-is-required"/>
                    <aui:validator name="alpha" />

                </aui:input>

            </td>
            <td>
                <aui:input name="t02Totalkm" type="text" label="" maxlength="7" value="">

                    <aui:validator name="required"  errorMessage="this-field-is-required"/>
                    <aui:validator name="digits" />

                </aui:input>

                 <input type="hidden" name="hdn" id="hdn" />


            </td>


       </tr>

    </table>

    <table id="dataTable1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" style="text-align:center;"><aui:button name="submitAction" type="submit" value="Apply" /></td>
            <td><aui:button name="addRow" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" /></td>

            <td><aui:button name="deleteRow" type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </aui:form>   </body> </html>
```

Comment: As the error says, "you cannot return from outside a function or method". Just remove the return statement and call your function `onSubmit="validateAllInputBoxes(event)"`

Comment: please explain it properly for better answers.

Comment: i tried with without return type.it is not working.

Comment: I am using AUI form and for static field I am using AUI Validator. And for dynamic I am using Java Script. I have written the code for text field validation. But I am getting the error in the below line. And first time only calling validateAllInputBoxes() and next time it is not calling and also even if text field is not empty it showing alert message "form could not be sent one input text field is empty".

Comment: Any body can answer my question.please....

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you do `onSubmit="return myFunction()"` it's to cancel event if `myFunction` returns `false`, continue if it returns `true`. 
However your function returns nothing, I don't think the use of `"return MyFunction()"` is appropriate.

Also, in `validateAllInputBoxes` you test `if(inputs[i].length==0)` but input text object
doesn't have a length property (that I know) you should try to test `inputs[i].value == null or inputs[i].value.length==0` instead.